# How to fix time step in box2d so that sprites move smoothly?

Tags: c++, box2d

The following is my timestep:

```
void step(float dt){
    static double UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1.0f/60.0f;
    static double MAX_CYCLES_PER_FRAME = 5;
    static double timeAccumulator = 0;

    timeAccumulator += dt;
    if (timeAccumulator > (MAX_CYCLES_PER_FRAME * UPDATE_INTERVAL))
    {
        timeAccumulator = UPDATE_INTERVAL;
    }

    int32 velocityIterations = 3;
    int32 positionIterations = 2;
    while (timeAccumulator >= UPDATE_INTERVAL)
    {
        timeAccumulator -= UPDATE_INTERVAL;
        this->world->Step(UPDATE_INTERVAL,
                          velocityIterations, positionIterations);
        this->world->ClearForces();
    }
}
```

While the game as such works great regardless of the framerate, it causes sprites to "tremble", or "stutter" even when the framerate is 60fps!

I think this is because each frame the sprite moves by a different amount, because each frame the number of times the while loop executes is different.

What is a better way to fix the time step ? I have read a number of articles on fixing the time step, and am very confused. The above "works" except for the stutter.

EDIT: Just to clarify, the tremble is very small! People with poor eyesight don't notice it, but it makes a game look very low budget if you look carefully. It makes the game look not smooth.

Comment: Your problem sounds like missing subpixel accuracy: assume that your sprites don't move in integer steps, if they end on x:0.99 they get drawn at x:0, next they move to 2.11 and will be drawn at 2. So instead of moving 1 pixel, your sprite jumps two. Try bilinear rendering of your sprites and see if that helps.

Comment: no no. The problem is not that - I just discovered - its called "temporal aliasing" XD Trying to figure out how to fix it. Has to do entirely with physics.

Comment: also shouldn't `timeAccumulator = UPDATE_INTERVAL;` be `timeAccumulator = MAX_CYCLES_PER_FRAME * UPDATE_INTERVAL;`?

Comment: That would cause spikey behaviour. It is better to slow down the game when the frame rate drops.

Comment: clamping already slows down the game... you just slow it down even further

Answer (score -1):

you don't clamp your timeAccumulator correctly:

```
timeAccumulator += dt;
if (timeAccumulator > (MAX_CYCLES_PER_FRAME * UPDATE_INTERVAL))
{
    timeAccumulator = UPDATE_INTERVAL;
}
```

should be

```
timeAccumulator = std::min(dt + timeAccumulator, MAX_CYCLES_PER_FRAME * UPDATE_INTERVAL);
```

Concerning the stepping: you'll need to interpolate the last full step with the next full step according to the left-over in `timeAccumulator`. There was a tutorial on this by Allan Bishop though the original site is no longer reachable (blog.allanbishop.com). Here's how his smooth step (only that last one with the fractional step) looks like:

```
// for the remaining timeAccumulator < UPDATE_INTERVAL
fixedTimestepAccumulatorRatio = timeAccumulator / UPDATE_INTERVAL;

private function smoothStates():void
{
    const oneMinusRatio:Number = 1.0 - fixedTimestepAccumulatorRatio;
    //Makes it easier to wrap up the Box2D body in another object so we can track other variables.
    for each (var body:Body in bodies)
    {
        var box2Dbody = body.box2DBody;
        texture.position.x = fixedTimestepAccumulatorRatio * box2Dbody.GetPosition().x + oneMinusRatio * body.previousPosition.x;
        texture.position.y = fixedTimestepAccumulatorRatio * box2Dbody.GetPosition().y + oneMinusRatio * body.previousPosition.y;
        texture.rotation = box2Dbody.GetAngle() * fixedTimestepAccumulatorRatio + oneMinusRatio * body.previousAngle;
    }
}
```

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem... have you tried it ? I think the problem is because of the variable nature of the while loop. This has to do with temporal aliasing. There is still plenty of stutter / jitter

Comment: Apparently I have to interpolate the time steps, but that seems really complicated. Haven't figured it out yet, and haven't found any code of someone else who has done it yet.